# Запрещение ajax-запроса с чужого сайта

Tags: ajax

Здравствуйте. Можно как-то запретить, чтобы с чужого сайта невозможно было сделать ajax-запрос?

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте рефера.

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_REFERRER']
```

Comment: Если с другого домена на ваш, то не получиться никак совершить, если у вас не стоит кеп-алив равный "*"